# How to execute Apache2 virtual server under different user/group with mpm_event

Tags: linux, apache, apache2, vhosts, ownership

I want to host a multisite server with different user/group for each site like :

```
/var/www/site0 = user0:groupuser0
/var/www/site1 = user1:groupuser1
```

I didn't find a way to change file ownership with specific group/user including/included www-data.

Everytime I execute phpinfo() it run as www-data for uid and gid.

I have see there is [mod_itk](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libapache2-mpm-itk)
and [mod_privileges](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_privileges.html) but it do not work with **mpm_event to have HTTP/2** running on the webserver (very important for performance).

So i'm asking here expert if there's a way to do it with mpm_event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the answer.

It was about php execution.

You can set specific user group by creating specific php-fpm execution pool located in

```
/etc/php/8.2/fpm/pool.d
```

Then the uid/gid can be correctly containerized inside the system.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. You do not show the changes required. You mention a filename that would vary based on the OS and PHP version which are not specified. Edit your post to be complete.